# Find the area of triangle

Tags: geometry, area

There is a square $ABCD$ of side $a$, points $E,F$ lies at centre of respectively $AB,CD$.
Line $AE$ intersect with $DF$ at $G$ and $BD$ at $H$. Find area of $DHG$.

I don't know why I can't add a comment but thanks for hint, I have already known how to do it

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $\text{area of }\triangle DHG=\text{area of }\triangle DAB-\text{area of }\triangle AHB-\text{area of }\triangle ADG$.............

Comment: Simpler might be $DHG=DHA-DGA$.

Answer (score 2):

No trig and no long calculations seem to be necessary here.

Drop the perpendiculars from $G$ and $H$ onto $\overline{AD}$ at $I$ and $J$ respectively.

$\hspace{2.5cm}$[image]

---

Since $\triangle JDH\simeq\triangle ADB$, we have that $\overline{JD}=\overline{JH}$

Since $\triangle JAH\simeq\triangle DAE$, we have that $\overline{JA}=2\overline{JH}$

Therefore, $\overline{JH}=\frac13\overline{AD}$

---

Since $\triangle IDG\simeq\triangle ADF$, we have that $\overline{ID}=2\overline{IG}$

Since $\triangle IAG\simeq\triangle DAE$, we have that $\overline{IA}=2\overline{IG}$

Therefore, $\overline{IG}=\frac14\overline{AD}$

---

Area of $\triangle DHA=\frac12\overline{JH}\times\overline{AD}=\frac16\overline{AD}^2=\frac16a^2$

Area of $\triangle DGA=\frac12\overline{IG}\times\overline{AD}=\frac18\overline{AD}^2=\frac18a^2$

Therefore, Area of $\triangle DHG=\frac16 a^2-\frac18 a^2=\frac1{24}a^2$

Answer (score 1):

One fact that I have always found useful, is that given two angles and an adjacent side, we can calculate area of a triangle by this simple identity: [Its a good exercise to prove the identity itself, need hints?]

$$Area = \frac{a^2}{2(\cot B + \cot C)}$$

So, in $\triangle DHA$, the identity gives us the area, $\frac{a^2}{2(1 + 2)} = \frac{a^2}{6}$.

And, in $\triangle DGA$, the identity again gives, $\frac{a^2}{2(2 + 2)} = \frac{a^2}{8}$.

Now what would you get when you subtract them both...?

Comment: +1 for the formula, but the geometry is so simple, I don't think trig is really needed.

Comment: @robjohn I saw that that were answers using geometry, so I wanted to give one using simple trig. Actually that formula is helpful in a number of cases, but is not generally introduced, so I wanted to give it here.

Comment: I see that we were also hit by the downvoter.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, and unlike this time he downvoted it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

NOW Join FC which intersects with DB at point O

- now see ADEF is a rectengle so G is the surely the midpoint of DF.
- NOW see CF||AE or in $\bigtriangleup$DFO GH||FO.so H is the midpoint of DO. so we have $\bigtriangleup$DGH=$\frac{1}{4}$.$\bigtriangleup$DFO
- NOW see that DB=$\sqrt{2}$ a and CF=$\sqrt{a^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}$=$\frac{\sqrt{5}a}{2}$
- now $\bigtriangleup$DFO IS similar to $\bigtriangleup$DOC as FB||CD
- so $\frac{DO}{BO}$=2
- $\frac{DO+BO}{BO}$=3
- $\frac{DB}{BO}$=3
- BO=$\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{3}$
- similarly FO=$\frac{\sqrt{5}a}{6}$
- now name $\angle$CFB=x and $\angle$DBA=y
- see tanx=2 and tany=1
- so now tan$\angle$FOB=tan{180$-$(x+y)}=$-$tan(x+y)=$\frac{tanx+tany}{tanxtany-1}$=3
- $(sink)^2$+$(cosk)^2$=1 [where k=$\angle$FOB]
- SO sink=$\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$
- now $\bigtriangleup$FOB=$\frac{1}{2}$.BO.FO.sink=$\frac{a^2}{12}$
- now $\bigtriangleup$DFB=$\frac{a^2}{4}$
- so $\bigtriangleup$DFO=$\frac{a^2}{4}$$-$$\frac{a^2}{12}$=$\frac{a^2}{6}$
- so $\bigtriangleup$DGH=$\frac{1}{4}$$\frac{a^2}{6}$=$\frac{a^2}{24}$[image]

Comment: @krishnan If you have used trig, I think my answer is good too :) See it?

Comment: its a nice solution of course if we know the materials you used,sawarnik.

Comment: That formula. You need the proof?

Comment: no.i have proved it already.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

## answer

AGH = ABDC - ( ABD + CHD + AGC)

### 1-□ ABDC

□ ABCD = a*a=a^2.....
□ ABCD = (a^2)......(i)

### 2- △ ABD

△ ABD = (a*a)/ 2 = a^2 /2....
△ ABD =(1/2) a^2......(ii)

### 3- △ CHD

△ CHD=( HD*KC) / 2....

### 3-1.Now:KC

△ KCD....KC=KD and CD =a....

KC^2 + KD^2 = CD^2....
<==> 2KC^2 = CD^2 = a^2....
<==> KC^2 = (a^2) / 2........
<==> KC= a/√2....

<==> KC= (a√2)/2......(1)

### 3-2.Now:HD

FB∥ CF ....F is the midpoint of CD....CF = FD = a/2
<==> CF/ FD = HI/ ID = 1
<==> HI= ID .......(2)

EC ∥ BF....G is the midpoint of AF....AG=GF
<==> AG/GF = AH/HI =1
<==> AH= HI .......(3)

from (ii) and (iii)
 in AD: AH=HI=ID
<==> AD= 3 ID)
<==> HD =( 2/3)AD....(4)

△ ADB....AD^2 = AB^2 + BD^2
<==> AD^2 = a^2 + a^2
<==> AD = √2a...(5)

from (4) and (5)...
HD = (2/3)√2a....(6)

So:
△ CHD=( HD*KC) / 2
<==> ( (2/3)√2a)*((a√2)/2)) / 2

<==>△ CHD =( 1/3) a^2....(iii)

### 4- △ AGC

△ AGC= (AC*LG )/2 = ( a* (LG))  / 2

### 4-1.Now LG

△ ACF ...AL=LC and AG=GF and LG ∥ CF
<==> LG= (1/2) CF = (1/2) (a/2) = a/4

<==> LG= a/4

So:△ AGC= (AC*LG )/2 = ( a* (LG))  / 2 = (a*(a/4)) /2 =(a^2 / 8)

<==> △ AGC = (1/8) a^2....(iiii)

==================
Now from
AGH = ABDC - ( ABD + CHD+AGC)
and (i) (ii) (iii) (iiii)

AGH =a^2 - ( (1/3) a^2 + (1/8) a^2 + (1/2)a^2 )

Finallly  area △ AGH = (1/24) a^2

---

DONE